# How to Route URL from one domain to another

Tags: asp.net, iis, url, url-rewriting

I am an C# ASP.NET developer. I am trying to route URL from one domain to another using Godaddy IIS Virtual dedicated server or Dedicated server for ASP.NET.

For example I have a website application for client_A in my server which is intended to be use by multiple clients with different products.

**An example URL:** www.myserver.com/client_A/product/bear/?productid=1 or using pretty URL www.myserver.com/A_Application/product/bear/1

I would like to setup for my client to point to client_A using his/her domain.

**My Client example URL will be**: www.hisserver.com/product/bear/?productid=1 or using pretty URL www.hisserver.com/product/bear/1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be for you client to set up their domain to simply point to your server, then use Apache virtual hosts to point that domain to the directory in question. I'm not sure if godaddy allows multiple virtual hosts like that, so you could also do it with a mod_rewrite based on the incoming Host.

Comment: I just edited my original question. Application A in my server is intended to be use by multiple clients with different products for each client. Will mod_rewrite still works for this? Is mod_rewrite supported in Godaddy?